# Class Or Framework To Help Build PHP RESTful API

Tags: php, api, rest

I am looking to create a RESTFul PHP based API, and I am wondering if there are any good prebuilt REST server classes or frameworks?

Basically just want a class to handle routing, and finally, it should be able to return back JSON or XML. I don't care about the VERB types (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE), because for example, if somebody wants to delete a record, I want them to be able to simply type in a URL into their browser to delete. If you look at the VERB, and only allow DELETE, its means this inst possible.

An example, is that I want to be able to write a simple class like:

```
class Customers {
    public function get($customer_id) {
        //{ "response" : [ { "first" : "Bob", "last" : "Smith", "company" : "ABC Inc." } ] }
    }

    public function delete($customer_id) {
       //{ "response" : "deleted" }
    }

    //POST
    public function create($first_name, $last_name, $company) {
       //{ "response" : "12322" }
    }
}
```

Which would create the following routes:

```
/customers/get/12322
/customers/delete/12322
/customers/create *post data*
```

Thanks greatly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Framework for PHP and creation of RESTful based web services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238125/best-framework-for-php-and-creation-of-restful-based-web-services)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Fat-Free Framework](http://fatfree.sourceforge.net), specifically `F3::map()`

Comment: Thanks, playing with Fat-Free Framework and loving it. Working out perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I've used http://code.google.com/p/php-rest-api/ as a base on a couple of large scale project.